# Does os.walk have a limit to the amount of files to walk through?

Tags: python, operating-system

I am trying to automate running a program and saving images from it using os.walk and os.Popen. The code is here:

```
#Loop through all files in directory
for root, dir, files, in os.walk(filepath):
    for file in files:
        #Find File Path of Song (need to not hard code)
        fp =  filepath +'\\' + str(file)
        print('Processing: ', fp)

        #Doulbe Check we haven't added before


        #Call Spek with that filepath
        subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Users\spitf_000\Downloads\spek-0.8.2\Spek\spek.exe', fp])

        #Implementing adaptive wait time based on file size
        file_size = os.stat(fp).st_size
        wait_time = (file_size/1000000)
        time.sleep(wait_time)           

        #Setting SAFE pyautogui
        #Can tune once the rest is stable
        pyautogui.FAIL_SAFE = True
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.6 #Need to figure out how to make this run faster, it seems that 0.5 is the least amount of pause time between inputs for 'safe' results


        #Key Presses to Save each file
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 's')
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'f4')
```

The problem I'm having is that the program will loop through roughly 400 out of the 5000 songs in the directory. It will then stop, and I cannot find an error message or anything.

Comment: I've answered the immediate question below. Receiving no error message from Python is surprising and I might suggest instrumenting the code more finely with print statements to see if you can find the last line that was executed. You can also try to answer your own question by isolating the os.walk (removing all code below the print line) and seeing if os.walk walks all your files as expected.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no limit to the number of files os.walk will walk through that is within the normal storage limits that Python has on your system. I use os.walk to walk through a library of well over 200,000 files in a structured hierarchy of directories regularly.